# Can browser make over 1 request at a time or at least wait for previous to start?

Tags: javascript, browser, httprequest

I would like to understand the browser requests behaviour and if we can to influence it on the example of Chrome. 
 **The question:** Why does browser cancel request with a delayed response? How can we wait for the first response with JS and then initiate a new request?

Let's say we want to download two files, however the server which provide the files is delayed in its responses. To model the situation I used the service with 5 seconds delay  http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/5000/url/
and test files from http://ovh.net/files/ (have no idea if it is safe)
Combining, we can start the delayed downloading

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <a  onClick="perform_request()" href="http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/5000/url/http://ovh.net/files/10Mb.dat" download> First file </a><br/>
        <a  onClick="perform_request()" href="http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/5000/url/http://ovh.net/files/1Mb.dat" download> Second file </a>
</body>
</html>
```

if we will not wait for 5 seconds for the first downloading to start and ask for the second file, the browser cancels the first request, and mechanism of this behaviour I am trying to understand.

[image]

Why does browser cancels the first request and can we influence that behaviour? 
Can we write a onClick JS function with the following pseudo code:

```
function perform_request():
    while true:
        if SomeProcessesWaitForResponse == true:
           await sleep(0.5sec)
        else:
           SomeProcessesWaitForResponse = true
           await request_file(waiting_time=10sec) //wait for response fo 10 seconds
           SomeProcessesWaitForResponse = false 
           break
```

I tried to use EventSource for this purpose, but seems like it works only with  'text/event-stream'